# Uncaught InvalidStateError: An attempt was made to use an object that is not, or is no longer, usable

Tags: javascript, ajax

This is the error I got:

```
Uncaught InvalidStateError: 
An attempt was made to use an object that is not, or is no longer, usable.
```

This is the code causing the error above:

```
function updateStudentDetails() {
    var name = $("#txtfull_name").val();
    var contact = $("#txtcontact_number").val();
    var status = $("#approval").val();
    var username = $("#UserName").val();
    var password = $("#Password").val();
    var ic_number = $("#txtic_number").val();
    var relation = $("#ddlrelation").val();
    var mail_id = $("#txtemailaddress").val();
    var address = $("#txtperm_address").val();
    var zipcode = $("#txtperm_postcode").val();
    var city = $("#txtperm_city").val();

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: servicePath + "/ParentDetailsUpdate?",
        dataType: "xml",
        success: updateStudentDetailsSuccess,
        error: dataError,
        data: {
            id: currentParentId,
            name: name,
            contact: contact,
            status: status,
            username: username,
            password: password,
            ic_num: ic_number,
            relation: relation,
            mail_id: mail_id,
            address: address,
            taman_id: tamanId,
            zip_code: zipcode,
            city: city,
            payment: '0'
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: The one variable you're not showing being set is `currentParentId`. Where does it come from?

Comment: the variable curentParentId and tamanId is the global variable

Comment: And what about servicePath variable which should contain part of the url for ajax request?